Equation in quaternions
Let $f,g:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ be quaternionic functions. Suppose that for any $q\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $I\in\mathbb{S}_{\mathbb{H}}=\{q\in\operatorname{Im}(\mathbb{H}):q^2=-1\}$ we have
$$
f(q)+Ig(q)=0.
$$
How to prove that both $f$ and $g$ are the zero function? Maybe this problem belong to a more general situation.
Thank you very much.

$$
\newcommand{\qq}{q_{*}}
$$
Suppose, for some $\qq$, that $f(\qq)$ is nonzero. Write your equation as
$$
Ig(q) = -f(q)
$$
This is suppose to be valid for any pure-vector unit quaternion $I$, so in particular, we have
$$
jg(\qq) = -f(\qq)\\
kg(\qq) = -f(\qq)
$$
from which we get
$$
jg(\qq) = k g(\qq)
$$
so
$$
(j-k) g(\qq) = 0
$$
hence $g(\qq) = 0$. From this, remembering that
$$
jg(\qq) = -f(\qq)\\
$$
we get that $f(\qq) = 0$, which is a contradiction. Hence our original assumption, that $f(\qq)$ is nonzero, must have been wrong. Hence $f$ is zero on its entire domain. Using your fundamental equality, so is $g$.
